# How to write latest record in Google Sheet formula and autofill?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet - table 1 below and all the data is given. Table 1 data is people(VenderNo) claim that they want to join event with what data(EventStartDate) and what booth number(BoothNo). So the data is duplicated because people update it with new line and never allowd to delete or update the existing record(table 1).

[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQYo6.png)

And I also have a Google sheet - table 2 below and only EventStartDate and BoothNo are given. All I want to do is the result like table 2's VenderNo. The purpose of table 2 is trying to summarize which vendor is eventually joining the event with latest booth number.

Ideal result like blow:

[Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaqZ8.png)

May I know how to write this formula in table 2 column C (VendorNo) with autofill function like ={ "VendorNo"; unique(General!A2:A) } without hand dragging the formula?

Any thoughts and thank you.

P.S.: I am sorry I couldn't post image above directly because I don't have enough reputation.

Revision 1 for Mike Result: (Yellow highlight mismatched, since v001 should not join the same event date with 2 booths)
[image]

Revision 2 for Mike Result: (Yellow highlight mismatched, since v004 added to 2022-11-11 for BoothNo A01.  BoothNo C01 doesn't erase as expected, Because same vendor(VendorNo) should only be with same date( EventStartDate) & latest booth selection(BoothNo))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
={"vendor";arrayformula(if(
iferror(vlookup(E2:E&"~"&F2:F,{B2:B&"~"&C2:C,A2:A,C2:C},3,0))
=
iferror(vlookup(vlookup(E2:E&"~"&F2:F,{B2:B&"~"&C2:C,A2:A},2,0)&"~"&E2:E,({unique({A2:A&"~"&B2:B}),(vlookup(unique({A2:A&"~"&B2:B}),SORT({A2:A&"~"&B2:B,C2:C,row(A2:A)},3,0),2,0))}),2,0),""),
iferror(vlookup(E2:E&"~"&F2:F,{B2:B&"~"&C2:C,A2:A},2,0)),""
))}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Mike, your answer is very close but I find mistake between there. I uploaded a picture to the post above. Yellow highlight is the wrong matching. Here I revised the formula to make it more sustainable ={"vendor v2";arrayformula(iferror(
if(E2:E&"~"&F2:F=vlookup(E2:E&"~"&RIGHT(F2:F,2),sort(arrayformula({B2:B&"~"&RIGHT(C2:C,2),B2:B&"~"&C2:C,B2:B,C2:C,A2:A}),2,0),2,0),
vlookup(E2:E&"~"&RIGHT(F2:F,2),sort(arrayformula({B2:B&"~"&RIGHT(C2:C,2),B2:B&"~"&C2:C,B2:B,C2:C,A2:A}),2,0),5,0),)))}

Comment: Please see image below with the yellow highlight mismatch. other result is fine.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OyrH_2yl_4a_6IM8TqMQ7AitvPqw1kYk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, Hello Mike. Thanks a lot. If you could give me email, I can share Google Sheets directly to you. Or download the excel link below: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTJG3bq9J6Q_7g_9dZpKZVhuxgaViTnC0C_YRfEqYBo1r3SR7_jehkzEHacjPAyb-Lmd75fVoyICRBU/pub?output=xlsx

Comment: Hello Mike, columns A,B,C are allowing people to add their wish for which date and boothNo(where) to join the event. As you know column E & F are summarising which VendorNo(Who) is going to join the BoothNo(Where) in EventStartDate(When). All 3 factors matched with the last records are the answer.

Comment: And from your latest formula is very close but VendorNo v004 are missing in columns E & F. any thoughts? VendorNo v004 has log on columns A,B,C but not showing up in column E & F.

Comment: Hello Mike, Revision 2 for Mike Result: please see image in my revised post above (Yellow highlight mismatched, since v004 added to 2022-11-11 for BoothNo A01. BoothNo C01 doesn't erase as expected, Because same vendor(VendorNo) should only be with same date( EventStartDate) & latest booth selection(BoothNo))

Comment: re-try ... I leave row#8 because C01 is greater than A01! What will be the next rule? if this is not the right answer, please make a complete set of test and give the expected output

Comment: Hello Mike, I haven't added any new rule. The formula should be based on columns A,B,C which log VendorNo, EventStartDate & BoothNo to finalize which Vendor(VendorNo) is going to join which EventStartDate with BoothNo.
If v001 joins 2022-11-11, booth number C01. And then v001 changed his mind to 2022-11-11,booth number A01. Then we will mark A01 as final. C01 & A01 has no bigger or smaller relationship. only the last record of VendorNo with EventStartDate and BoothNo is the principle of the formula.

Comment: So there is no final output. I will keep enter data in columns A,B,C to test columns E & F to verify the formula. As long as you understand "the last record of VendorNo with EventStartDate and BoothNo is the principle of the formula." Then I am convinced that you could help me to solve the problem easily.

Comment: Above image you posted. v004 is the latest record which decided to join event on 2022-11-11 and selected boothNo as A01. So this should be marked as final but not c01 for v004

Comment: ok, instead of checking greater or not I will check the row in column A. Once again, provide a complete set with expected output. I will correct for the last time.

Comment: I am sorry Mike, I gave out complete set to you already. I just try adding dummy data in columns A,B,C to test the formula. There is only one rule for the formula: getting the latest record(next row input of columns A,B,C is greater than previous row input of columns A,B,C) of VendorNo, EventStartDate & BoothNo.

Comment: done, let me know if everything is now ok!

Comment: Mike, you are the best. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Formula for that. Just select your columns and go to "Data" ->"Sort data"->"advanced sort settings" and then sort by column "EventStartDate" and secondly add sort by another column and add "BoothNo".
In the end you can run a data clean up to remove duplicates. You find it also under data.

[image]

Comment: Hello PySeeker, Thank you for your reply, but I have no choice to use 1 formula in Table 2 column C. Because I am using Appsheet to get data automatically. It is easy if using assorted sorting and remove duplication. Therefore, Any thoughts on using 1 formula in Table 2 column C?

Answer (score 0):

to get the latest update from your table 1 you can use:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:C, B2:B, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

for your table 2 try:

```
={"VN"; INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(E2:E&F2:F, 
 SORTN(SORT({B2:B&C2:C, A2:C}, B2:B, 0), 9^9, 2, 2, 1), 2, 0)))}
```

[image]